# How can I fix 'Unable to find an element' error when testing my React.js form with schema errors?

Tags: reactjs, forms, schema

I'm making a form for a project that should be able to accept name, address, and phone number. It is also able to select toppings, as well as a box for special instructions. The name needs to be at least 2 characters. All of the elements work. But, I keep getting a error saying that it can find my error message. This is the message...

Unable to find an element with the text: name must be at least 2 characters. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

I tried moving the error message around to see if the test could see the message and finally i tried to create a seperate function that handles the error message.

These are my code files,

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PizzaForm from './Components/PizzaForm';
import './App.css'; 

const App = () => {
return (
<div>
<Routes>
<Route path="/" element={
<div className="center-content">
<img src="/IMG_1758.jpg" alt="Big Tavo" className='tavio-image'/>
<Link id="order-pizza" to="/pizza" 
className="big-link">Welcome! To Big Tavo's Pizza!</Link>
</div>
} />
<Route path="/pizza" element={<PizzaForm />} />
</Routes>
</div>
);
};

export default App;
```

PizzaForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import yup from 'yup';
import schema from './valadation/formSchema'

const PizzaForm = () => {
const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
Name: '',
address: '',
phoneNumber: '',
size: '',
toppings: [],
specialText: ''
});

const [nameError, setNameError] = useState('');
const [postError, setPostError] = useState('');

const handleChanges = (event) => {
if (event.target.type === 'checkbox') {
setFormValues({
...formValues,
toppings: [...formValues.toppings, event.target.value]
});
} else {
setFormValues({
...formValues,
[event.target.name]: event.target.value
});
}
};

const getErrorMessage = (matcher) => {
if (matcher && nameError && nameError.includes(matcher)) {
return <div>{nameError}</div>;
}

return null;
};

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

schema.validate(formValues)
.then(() => {
axios.post('https://reqres.in/api/orders', formValues)
.then(res => {
console.log(res.data);
setFormValues({
Name: '',
address: '',
phoneNumber: '',
size: '',
toppings: [],
specialText: ''
});
})
    
.catch(err => console.log(err));
setPostError('An error occurred 
while submitting the form. Please
try again.');
})

.catch((err) => {
console.log(err.errors);
setNameError(err.errors[0] || '');
});

};


return (
<div>
<h1>Big Tavo's Pizza</h1>
<form id="pizza-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<div/>
<div>
<label>
Name
<input
id="name-input"
name="Name"
value={formValues.Name}
onChange={handleChanges}
/>
{getErrorMessage('name must be at least 2 characters')}
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
Address
<input id="address-input" 
name="address" value=   
{formValues.address} 
onChange={handleChanges}/>
</label>
<label>
Phone Number
<input id="phone-number-input" 
name="phoneNumber" 
value={formValues.phoneNumber} 
onChange={handleChanges} />
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
Size
<select id="size-dropdown" 
name="size" 
value={formValues.size} 
onChange={handleChanges}>
<option value="">--Select Size--</option>
<option value="small">Small</option>
<option value="medium">Medium</option>
<option value="large">Large</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" 
name="toppings" 
value="cheese" 
onChange={handleChanges} />
Cheese
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" 
name="toppings" 
value="pepperoni" 
onChange={handleChanges} />
Pepperoni
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" 
name="toppings" 
value="sausage" 
onChange={handleChanges} />
Sausage
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" 
name="toppings" 
value="chicken" 
onChange={handleChanges} />
Chicken
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox"     
name="toppings"      
value="ham"     
onChange={handleChanges} />
Ham
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
Special Instructions
<input id="special-text" 
name="specialText" 
value= {formValues.specialText} 
onChange={handleChanges} />
</label>
</div>
<div>
<button id="order-button" 
type="submit">Add to Order
</button>
</div>
{postError && <div>{postError}</div>}
</form>
</div>
);

};

export default PizzaForm;
```

formSchema.js

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

const schema = yup.object().shape({
Name: yup
.string()
.required('Name is required')
.min(2, 'name must be at least 2 characters'),
});

export default schema;
```